# jenkins pipeline exposing creds in output

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, jenkins-groovy

So I am running Terraform on Jenkins and I have a jenkins job that runs "terraform-plan".

That job runs a groovy script which picks up the cred using:

```
if [ "${env.repo_name}" = "repo5" ]; then
   export TF_VAR_github_token=${getgithubtokenfortf()["gitHubToken"]};
fi
```

and the getgithubtokenfortf is actually another script that is called by the terraform plan script:

```
def call() {
  def gitHubToken
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'xxxx', variable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN')]) {
      gitHubToken = GITHUB_TOKEN
  }

  [gitHubToken: gitHubToken]
}
```

and the credentialsId is stored in Jenkins with the token value!

Now the issue is that - when I run the Terraform PLan job in jenkins in the console output I see the value of the token exposed.

```
[ repo5 = repo5 ]
export TF_VAR_github_token=xxxxx(valuefromtokenbeingexposedhere)
```

now what I want is that ... I dont want the value being exposed like this^ .. I dont want it to be printing out the value of the token.

how do I fix?

Comment: The secrets are safe only inside the `withCredentials` block. If you store it in a variable and plan to use it outside the block, jenkins can not protect those secrets. I recommend running all your logic inside the `withCrednetails`  block.

Comment: @Ram i do not store the token in the variable .. i have stored in jenkins and as you see the code it calls the jenkins cred using with withCredentials block. I am not sure where and what is wrong..

Comment: ‘gitHubToken=GITHUB_TOKEN’ is where you are using an additional variable

Comment: @Ram thank u.. do u have any idea how I can do that or help me in modifying this? I would appreciate it

Comment: [GitHub App authentication support released](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/04/16/github-app-authentication/)

Comment: Also , see [Jenkins Injection via Interpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#injection-via-interpolation)